# How to read from one S3 bucket and write to another in pyspark?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark

I tried doing the following - set specific configs for each bucket - to read from one S3 bucket and write to the other. The two buckets have different credentials and belong to different accounts. However, the reading only works for the first bucket. That is, if we access the first bucket first, the second will never be available (vice-versa).

```
import os

## B1 CONF
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.bucket.b1.access.key", B1_ACCESS_KEY)
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.bucket.b1.secret.key", B1_SECRET_KEY)
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.bucket.b1.endpoint", B1_ENDPOINT)

## B2 CONF

spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.bucket.b2.access.key", B2_ACCESS_KEY)
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.bucket.b2.secret.key", B2_SECRET_KEY)
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.bucket.b2.endpoint", B2_ENDPOINT)

df1 = spark.read.parquet("s3a://" + B1_BUCKET_NAME + "/somepath")
df.show()

df2 = spark.read.parquet("s3a://" + B2_BUCKET_NAME + "/somepath")
od.show()
```

The error is:
`Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o915.parquet.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage X failed N times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.15 in stage X (TID M, IP, executor T): java.io.IOException: Bucket b2 does not exist`

Is there any other way to access two different buckets at the same time?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @tushaR Nope, didn't find it. I think I just moved the source files to the destination bucket and worked on that single bucket.

Comment: Thanks. I read somewhere it's difficult (may be not possible) to create multiple glue context within same application.